# Deploy jars in gemfire cache

Tags: gemfire

I am studying gemfire and getting my hands dirty. I came across this concept of deploying jars into gemfire.
My question is why and what type of jars would one deploy in to gemfire cache that would become native to gemfire. 
Can you list some scenarios that would clarify this concept of deploying jars in to gemfire ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write [Functions](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) that can be executed within the Geode server process. Functions are a quick way of iterating over the data in Geode in parallel OR implementing your custom aggregate.

You can also implement CacheLoaders to load data into Geode and [CacheListeners/AsyncEventListeners](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/CacheWriter+and+CacheListener+Best+Practices) to write data from Geode into another data source.

Your functions, Listeners, Writers can be bundled in a jar and then deployed on the Geode servers.